# Sorting array of type of object respecting to one of the object values

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, object, element

i have a class called student, the class have two elements (Name, ID).
in my main class, i have created about 10 students in an array i called it students,

now i want to sort the the students array respecting the ID, or the name!!

if i used this line of code

```
array.sort(students);
```

is there a way to use the sort method and choose which element i want to sort the array with???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Array.Sort(array, (s1, s2) => s1.Name.CompareTo(s2.Name));
```

You can define the comparator function however you want to get different sorting orders.

Comment: i have a question, how i can choose which indices in the array i want to sort?

Comment: That's a good question. I think you would either have to extract a subset of the array and sort that, or have your student class implement IComparable and then pass the starting index and length to Array.Sort(). It doesn't look like there is a overload of Array.Sort() that allows you to specify start index and length as well as an inline comparison function. You could also ask that as a new SO question, someone else might have a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list for this.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>{ new Student(), new Student(), new Student() }
```

then sort that list with LINQ

```
var sortedStuds = students.OrderBy(s => s.ID).ToList();
```

where the `s` is a `Student` object

Comment: Unnecessarily inefficient. `List<T>` has a `Sort` method that sorts in-place. (And so does `Array.Sort`.)

Comment: true, but I didn't know efficiency was a problem. BTW I was going to use `Sort`, but I used it somewhere else and got fussed at for it. And I just like List<T> :)

Answer (score 1):

If it’s an array, the most efficient way is to use `Array.Sort`:

```
Array.Sort(array, (s1, s2) => s1.Name.CompareTo(s2.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq:

```
sortedStudents1 = students.OrderBy(s=>s.Name).ToList();
sortedStudents2 = students.OrderBy(s=>s.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

While I also prefer the LINQ solution, you could alternatively make your Student class implement IComparable, which could give you more complex sorting options without having to write an in-line function every time.